# Progress status in a long php script in possible?

Tags: php

i have this very simple php script:

```
<?php 
require 'functions.php';
$token = "some-number";
$id = "other-number";
$albums = get_url_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$id."/albums?access_token=".$token);
$aObject = json_decode($albums, true);
foreach ($aObject['data'] as $i => $a) {
    $photos = get_url_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$a['id']."/photos?access_token=".$token);
    $bObject = json_decode($photos, true);
    foreach ($bObject['data'] as $y => $b) {
        if (strpos($b['name'],"#test1") !== false) {  
            echo($b['name']."<br>".$b['source']."<br>".$b['created_time']."<br>");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The execution time is always more than 10 seconds, is any way to notify the user with a perceptual text or something?

Comment: how do you call the script? if you call it via javascript you could display a message, if you call it directly via a url in the browser you can't post a message to notify the user

Comment: loading the page, where this script is.

Comment: then I dont see any possibility to display a status text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I learned something new.

it is possible. Look there: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/5153-status-note-scripts-run-long-time

You could display message at the beginning of the script execution and hide it via javascript on the end of the execution.

I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: Note that you can't flush() if you're using a Gzip output buffer... and you may need to tweak your server settings to flush() immediately.  more information at the docs:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Answer (score 0):

How about asynch load with js or jquery